# Do any "All In One" Printer/Scanners work on Linux?

Tags: linux, printing

> **Mod note**: The entire network is pretty against shopping recommendation questions; there was an attempt to edit this one to avoid it, but it seems to have failed. The goal is "how do I decide which printer to buy", not "which printer should I buy". If you're naming a specific model in your answer, you're probably doing it wrong

I am interested in purchasing a printer and scanner and would very much like the convenience of using an all-in-one model. The issue is that I am a very strict user of Debian GNU/Linux. I have heard very bad things about all-in-one support.

I'm looking for low-end (preferably even store-bought models) that I can safely print and scan with, using free software. If I have to install a non-free binary driver; I would do so, but it wouldn't be my preference. However, I do want to ensure it works with Debian.

What resources can I consult before buying to ensure the model I select will work?
And if only a few models work, how can I find the needle in the haystack?

Comment: Note that [shopping recommendations are generally not acceptable on the Stack Exchange network](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/760). On this particular site, see [this meta thread](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600/hardware-recommendations-whats-the-limit). A straight model recommendation is useless because there'll be new models in 6 months. I've edited the question to be more useful: how to fish, rather than finding a particular fish.

Comment: Thanks, good point! And, yes you are correct that is more what I was after was how to look. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site helps find linux-compatible printers: http://linuxdeal.com/printers.php?type=aio

This site helps let you know if printers you already have or want are linux-compatible: http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Comment: I found a model called an HP Desktjet 2050, and it was recommended on the hplip site. It printed fine but the scanner did not work. I upgraded to hplip in unstable and it all works. Thanks for all the answers!